# Asking 'how much'?

Tags: politeness, phrases

Which of these is a more appropriate/polite way of asking how much something costs without specifying the object? 
(I'm working at a very low level, so please be straightforward - no kanji, please explain with as much as English as possible! xD)

いくら

**OR**

いかばかり

Or something else?

Additionally, why is it that the か is dropped when asking these questions? Do the phrases mean the same WITH か ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with these two choices?

Comment: The first one came from a quick google search, the second came from a dictionary. I know that there's a lot of other choices, but these were the two I came across. :)

Comment: いかばかり is a phrase Shakespeare would use :)

Comment: @broccoliforest Oh! I had no idea :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using it during conversation and the other person can identify which object you are referring, you can use:

> いくらですか。

If you want to make it more respectful or more formal, you can ask:

> おいくらですか。

If you are talking on phone, or there are so many things you can talk about, it will be confusing for that person what exactly you re asking about. In that case, you can use:

> この`<object>`はいくらですか。

..............................................................

Out of the very basic greetings:

- O-genki desuka : お元気{げんき}ですか
- O-kage sama de genki desu : おかげさまで元気{げんき}です
- O-yasumi nasai : おやすみなさい
- O-namae wa nan desuka : お名前{なまえ}は何ですか
- O-tanjyoubi omedetou gozaimasu : お誕生日{たんじょうび}おめでとうございます。

All these greetings are used to greet another person, and thus the respect word, O is added in all these sentences.

Comment: May I ask.. how do you pronounce  the 'お' in 'おいくらですか'? 
Is it 'OI', 'OH', or something different? I'm guessing it's the first one, but I'm not sure. :P

Comment: @BakaNeko http://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%8A/#ja

Comment: Its simple "O-ikura desuka", asme as "O-genki desuka"....
The "O" adds the respect to the statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! If it's not too much trouble, are there any other examples or notable phrases where adding 'O-' would make more respectful? I can't imagine it working for everything. :)

Comment: baka-neko, edited the answer to answer your comment...pls check..